# How to convert from any large arbitrary base to another

Tags: algorithm, math, radix

What I’d like to do is to convert a string from one "alphabet" to another, much like converting numbers between bases, but more abstract and with arbitrary digits.

For instance, converting "255" from the alphabet "0123456789" to the alphabet "0123456789ABCDEF" would result in "FF". One way to do this is to convert the input string into an integer, and then back again. Like so: (pseudocode)

```
int decode(string input, string alphabet) {
  int value = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    int index = alphabet.indexOf(input[i]);
    value += index * pow(alphabet.length, input.length - i - 1);
  }
  return value;
}

string encode(int value, string alphabet) {
  string encoded = "";
  while(value > 0) {
    int index = value % alphabet.length;
    encoded = alphabet[index] + encoded;
    value = floor(value / alphabet.length);
  }
  return encoded;
}
```

Such that `decode("255", "0123456789")` returns the integer 255, and `encode(255, "0123456789ABCDEF")` returns `"FF"`.

This works for small alphabets, but I’d like to be able to use base 26 (all the uppercase letters) or base 52 (uppercase and lowercase) or base 62 (uppercase, lowercase and digits), and values that are potentially over a hundred digits. The algorithm above would, theoretically, work for such alphabets, but, in practice, I’m running into integer overflow because the numbers get so big so fast when you start doing 62^100.

What I’m wondering is if there is an algorithm to do a conversion like this without having to keep up with such gigantic integers? Perhaps a way to begin the output of the result before the entire input string has been processed?

My intuition tells me that it might be possible, but my math skills are lacking. Any help would be appreciated.

There are a few similar questions here on StackOverflow, but none seem to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You'll need a "bigint" math library (e.g., [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)) if you want to store it like an integer. Also, std::strtol() will do up to base 36 (digits plus letters, not case sensitive), but beware overflow.

Comment: Why do you need to convert whole strings at a time, rather than individual characters? Is this an attempt at optimization?

Comment: Good question.  I'm sure there's a mathematical formula that will do it, but the question is whether it's tractable.

Comment: You can do it in parts if you can find a (reasonably small) value V where V = base1 raised to the N1 power and V = base2 raised to the N2 power, where all values are integers.

Answer (score 2):

A general way to store numbers in an arbitrary  base would be to store it as an array of integers. Minimally, a number would be denoted by a base and array of int (or short or long depending on the range of bases you want) representing different digits in that base.

Next, you need to implement multiplication in that arbitrary base.

After that you can implement conversion (clue: if x is the old base, calculate x, x^2, x^3,..., in the new base. After that, multiply digits from old base accordingly to these numbers and then add them up).

Answer (score 0):

Java-like Pseudocode:

```
ArbitraryBaseNumber source = new ArbitraryBaseNumber(11,"103A"); 
ArbitraryBaseNumber target = new ArbitraryBaseNumber(3,"0");

for(int digit : base3Num.getDigitListAsIntegers()) { // [1,0,3,10]
    target.incrementBy(digit);
    if(not final digit) {
        target.multiplyBy(source.base);
    }
}
```

The challenge that remains, of course, is to implement ArbitraryBaseNumber, with `incrementBy(int)` and `multiplyBy(int)` methods. Essentially to do that, you do in code exactly what a schoolchild does when doing addition and long-multiplication on paper. Google and you'll find example.